# Trie or Set in Python

Tags: python, set, trie

I have a list of 100k words. I wish to search very efficiently if a word I read exists in this known list of words. Which of the two data structures can I search faster in a Trie or a Set while implementing in Python?

Comment: Theoretically a set, O(1). In reality, it depends. Why don't you try it?

Comment: A trie would also provide O(1) lookups. (Both the trie lookup and the hashing operation required by the set would be linear in the length of the search term.)

Comment: @chepner: Yar. The differences arise in the non-theoretical aspects. `set` hashing is usually only a few semi-random accesses (finding the non-colliding bucket). A trie involves traversing a tree, which means tons of effectively random memory accesses. In practice, I'd expect the trie to be a little slower in the case where the word exists, and a little faster when it doesn't (early rejection), but the difference is immaterial in 99% of programs that need to do it. And my expectations count for nothing; they have to profile if they're in that 1% where the speed *really* matters.

Comment: Which structure runs faster on your data set?  Hypothetical questions do not work well on Stack Overflow.  How would we know the answer better than your computer?  We expect you to perform basic research before posting a question; post the timing results if you have any questions about this issue.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Depending on how the tree is constructed, the overhead could be minimal . My point was that asymptotically, a trie isn't any worse than a set.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just "in or not", no checking by prefix or suffix or anything, just use a `set`. They're built-in, which by itself makes them more convenient, and they're faster than anything you'll implement by hand in Python. Tries have their place, but for simple membership tests, `set`s will be just fine in almost all cases. Don't prematurely optimize; if it works fast enough with a `set`, there's no reason to even consider another option.

Answer (score 2):

A set (hash table) is always better if you just need to check if a word already exists.  The (amortized) time complexity is constant.
A trie makes sense for other use cases, such as finding words that already exist that start with certain prefix.

Answer (score 2):

To add up to what other friends have commented, `set` is definitely preferable.

Written this benchmark comparing python `set` to `marisa-trie` which is:

> Static memory-efficient Trie-like structures for Python

The results are almost 10 magnitude in favor of `set`:

```
function [trie_performance_test] finished in 22 ms
function [set_performance_test] finished in 2 ms
```

Code:

```
# pip install marisa-trie
import functools
from timeit import default_timer as timer

import marisa_trie

import requests

word_site = "http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain"

response = requests.get(word_site)
WORDS = [w.decode('utf8') for w in response.content.splitlines()]

def timeit(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def newfunc(*args, **kwargs):
        startTime = timer()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        elapsedTime = timer() - startTime
        print('function [{}] finished in {} ms'.format(
            func.__name__, int(elapsedTime * 1000)))
    return newfunc

@timeit
def trie_performance_test(words=WORDS):
    trie = marisa_trie.Trie(words)
    for key in words:
        key_id = trie.get(key)

@timeit
def set_performance_test(words=WORDS):
    words_set = set(words)
    for key in words:
        if key in words_set:
            pass

trie_performance_test()

set_performance_test()
```